# How to map external request IDs to Spark Job IDs for Spark instrumentation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have deployed a system of Analytics APIs that internally uses PySpark to serve requests to our customers. Since, we expect a very high scale of incoming requests at any time, we are interested in instrumenting Spark, so as to understand the various bottlenecks with our implementation of it. We already have monitoring solutions in place that give us a break down of time-taken at component-level for each of our services. Diving deep on this we know that for the same API call, a number of times Spark arbitrarily takes a long time while at other times it returns early. This leads to random unexpected response times for our APIs.

Therefore, we have decided to learn more about the cause behind such spikes in time taken by Spark. Since, this is a production environment, we decided to implement Spark Listeners for instrumentation purposes. However, given that we have a number of different APIs that can be called in parallel, there is no way for us to confidently know which Spark Jobs are being spawned by which API call.

We tried retrieving more information through the history server but again there was no way to know which jobs related to which API call.

In a nutshell, we are looking for any way to know which set of Spark jobs are being called by any of our APIs. We have unique requestIds for our APIs and would want to maintain a one-to-many relationship between the two.